# Increment remaining row values in a column based on changing one value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a round robin scenario when new leads come in.
When a lead comes in, the following table named "round_robin" will find the position '1' and send the lead data there

```
Name      Type           Attributes   Null    Default Extra
id        int(11)                     No      None    AUTO_INCREMENT
on_off    text                        Yes     NULL    
cname     text                        Yes     NULL   
position  int(11)                     Yes     NULL   
email     varchar(100)                Yes     NULL
```

I have some knowledge of PHP so if some coding I used is way off, thats likely why.

This is the code I've started on.

```
$round_robin_companies = "SELECT * FROM round_robin";
$position_one = "SELECT position FROM round_robin WHERE postion = '1' ";
$query = "SELECT * FROM round_robin WHERE position = '$position'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result === 1) exit();
else {
    UPDATE $position_one SET position='$row_count';
    while ($query <= $row_count) {
        $row_count++;
    }
}
```

Basically, when a new row is added in a table called leads, I need Company One position to change to `$row_count (3)` and all the remaining positions to increment down one.

So Company Two position would be 1 and be next in the queue and Company Three would become 2.  I want to use row count because I will be adding more companies in the future.

```
id  on_off  cname           position   email
1       on      Company One     1          C1@email.com
2       on      Company Two     2          C2@email.com
3       on      Company Three   3          C3@email.com
```

Comment: Your logical requirements are not clear to me.

Comment: Can you help me be more specific?  What am I not providing?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been removed from PHP. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Just ad another row where you keep score, or how often you have given them an item. Then you can use that row in your select to get the one with the lowest score/.

Comment: You may be better off adding a date to the record - when a new lead comes in, update the record with the current date.  Then you could order the rows by this date which should produce them in the correct order

Comment: @NigelRen are you suggesting that instead of position?  So new lead comes in, find oldest date, give that company the lead, and then apply time stamp to that company?